# How do I insert the current date into an Oracle table using a Unix shell script?

Tags: oracle, bash, scripting

I am using the Bash shell and am new to shell scripting.

I have to insert the current system date and time into an Oracle table which has one "date" column (datatype is `timestamp(6)`) using a shell script.

How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you you have to do this in Bash? Oracle has `sysdate`.

Answer (score 0):

to get the time stamp from shell, you can use `date +%s` (long value) and insert into your table.